# How to fix edges on bottom part of my handle?

Tags: edges

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want it to look the same as the top handle of the cup in the fourth pic where there's a clear cut of 4 edges

Comment: Hello :). What exactly do you want to fix? Move the edges co they're centered? It's not really clear from the images.

Comment: Hey, I explained at the bottom. The edges that connect the handle to the cup are in excess and disfigure the placement of the handle on the bottom part when I only want there to be four lines that form a square just like how it looks at the top part of the handle.

Comment: Well, why not just delete those edges? That will clean it up and you can then add another loopcut :)